# Align Paragraph at the center of the page

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using itext to generate pdf file. I want to align my title in the middle of the page. Presently i am using like this

```
Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();  
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    preface.add(new Paragraph(" "));
}
```

Is it correct or is there any another best way to do this.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use [`Paragraph#setAlignment(int)`](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph#31vl8eiucb) :

```
Paragraph preface = new Paragraph(); 
preface.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

See the `ALIGN_*` constants in the [`Element`](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.Element) interface for more possible values.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a solution to Itext7 then you can use the method `setTextAlignment(...)`.

Example:

```
Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
// add text
preface.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 public static final String DEST = "results/tables/centered_text.pdf";


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new CenteredTextInCell().createPdf(DEST);
}

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD);
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Test", font);
    para.setLeading(0, 1);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setMinimumHeight(50);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    cell.addElement(para);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of your solution compared to the much simpler solution in the accepted answer?

Comment: *"The following line doesn't really make sense: `p1.setAlignment(Element.TABLE)`"* - I don't see that code anywhere here, neither in the question nor in any answer.

Comment: you're using a version of iText that is really, really old. The following line doesn't really make sense: preface.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER); so use this method instead above older itext version cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE); this method much faster and better

Comment: `Paragraph.setAlignment` is still present in the most current iText 5.5.x versions, and your code definitively cannot claim being iText 7 code. So why  do you claim that I am using a version of iText which is *really, really old*? Furthermore, I have not timed the methods, so I cannot say your claim that your method is faster is wrong. But based on what do you claim it is *better*?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is an old version, but for PdfWriter these methods weren't there.  Instead I used:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This too shall pass");
p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
```

Answer (score 3):

If any one is looking for .NET/C# version, below is how I achieved the CENTER alignment.

I am using iText7 library for .NET/C#, and I achieved this using :

```
Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
preface.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (itext 5.0.5 ):

```
Paragraph p3= new Paragraph("Hello" );
  p3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have searching solution for this to align PdfPCell text into right and also center. After modify and change the code sequence it is work.

This code is not work to align text to center.

```
              PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
              cell.addElement(new Phrase("Testing Page");
              cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
              table.addCell(cell);
```

After modifying code with this , it is working now.

```
              Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Testing Page");
              //Pass Paragraph object into PdfPCell 
              PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(p);
              cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
              table.addCell(cell);
```