# itext (Text - Pdf) center alignment

Tags: java, text, pdf-generation, itext, text-alignment

I am using itext to generate pdf file. I want to align my text in the middle of the page. My input file looks like in the below format

We refer to the ISDA Credit Support Annex dated as of 1 Oct 2009. Below is the data.

```
  Portfolio MTM                                               USD 24,479,059.69
  Independent Amount                                          USD 0.00
  Threshold                                                   USD 1,000,000.00
  Credit Support Amount / Exposure                            USD 23,479,059.69

  Credit Support Balance                                      USD 26,140,600.00

  Net Margin Requirement                                      USD 2660940.31

            Minimum Transfer Amount                           USD 250,000.00
            Rounding Amount                                   USD 10,000.00

  Delivery amount                                             USD 2670000
```

**My Java code is the below**

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
     InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(in);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)  {
    Paragraph para =new Paragraph(strLine+"\n");
    para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

    document.add(para);
    }

    document.close();
```

While trying to generate the Pdf file my alignment for the below data is not properly working.
Please let me know whether the above code is correct.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try ALIGN_CENTER instead

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph(strLine+"\n");
para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

[FROM THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373269/align-paragraph-at-the-center-of-the-page)

Comment: Hi Todd, Thanks for your Swift response. I tried it already, but no hope. The text alignment are varying for each row and it is not proper.

Comment: picture? more detailed description, if possible?

Comment: Its not Picture. Its a text file with some data. Please check the URL for more info.  http://imgur.com/a/UzdPd