# iText 7 - Center align text and paragraphs

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I'm trying to center align a block of text, however getting inconsistent results. Here is a rough idea of my code:

```
baseCanvas.ShowTextAligned("Header 1", 555, 839, TextAlignment.CENTER, 0);
baseCanvas.ShowTextAligned("Test test test ...", 240, 809, TextAlignment.CENTER, 0);
```

Here is the PDF Output:

[image: Output]

However I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image: Design]

I've checked the iText documentation, but is there a way to do this without having to create tables and cells?

Comment: Do any of these work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373269/align-paragraph-at-the-center-of-the-page

Comment: @KSib No, that doesn't work because those answers are for iText 5 and the question says that iText 7 is used.

Answer (score 7):

When you do:

```
baseCanvas.ShowTextAligned("Some text", x, y, TextAlignment.CENTER, 0);
```

Then you want the coordinate `(x, y)` to coincide with the middle of the text `"some text"`.

In your code snippet, you are centering some text around the coordinate `(555, 839)` and some text around the coordinate `(40, 809)` which explains the difference.

Since you are using iText 7, why don't you take advantage of the fact that you can now easily position `Paragraph` objects at absolute positions? The [iText 7 jump-start tutorial for .NET](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/sharp/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks) already introduces some of the basic building blocks, but the [Building blocks tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/) goes into more depth.

Take a look at the first example of [chapter 2](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2) and adapt it like this:

```
PdfPage page = pdf.AddNewPage();
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(36, 650, 100, 100);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, rectangle);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_BOLD);
Text title =
    new Text("The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde").SetFont(bold);
Text author = new Text("Robert Louis Stevenson").SetFont(font);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph().Add(title).Add(" by ").Add(author);
p.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
canvas.Add(p);
canvas.Close();
```

This should add the text inside the rectangle `(36, 650, 100, 100)` and center all content.

Comment: This is doing the trick. Thank you. 

How would I then rotate a block of text, as I'm not specifying an angle?

Comment: Any info on the above, @bruno?

Comment: That's a different question. Some objects can be rotated; sometimes creating a `PdfXObject` is required (and you can rotate those).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Appreciate it's a new question, however my original method "baseCanvas.ShowTextAligned..." allowed a radius to be passed as a parameter. Would I have to convert the rectangle or the paragraph to a PdfXObject?

Comment: The `ShowTextAligned()` method in `Canvas` also allowed you to pass a radius. See http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/RootElement.html#showTextAligned-com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph-float-float-int-com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment-com.itextpdf.layout.property.VerticalAlignment-float- The main difference is that the radius in iText 5 is expressed in degrees, whereas the radius in iText 7 is expressed in radians. Your initial comment wasn't about `ShowTextAligned()`; it was about rotating a *block* of text. Your comments confuse me.

Comment: Hi Bruno. Previously I was able to rotate text easily by passing a degree. How would I be able to rotate the text with the chosen answer example above? Thank you.

Comment: If you use `ShowTextAligned()`, convert degrees into radians as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677052/) and use that value for the `radAngle` parameter. If you use `canvas.Add(p)`, check which properties you can set on the `p` object [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/appendix/b-blockelement). As you can see, there's a method `SetRotationAngle()`. This method is demonstrated [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2) (see figure 5.9). Read the documentation!

Comment: since march 2020 those links are broken :(

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this.  Where the document is created, get the width of the document.

```
var document = new Document(pdfDoc);
var pageSize = pdfDoc.GetDefaultPageSize();
var width = pageSize.GetWidth() - document.GetLeftMargin() - document.GetRightMargin();
```

Then create the paragraph with this function.

```
private Paragraph CenteredParagraph(Text text, float width)
{
    var tabStops = new List<TabStop> { new TabStop(width / 2, TabAlignment.CENTER) };
    var output = new Paragraph().AddTabStops(tabStops);
    output.Add(new Tab())
            .Add(text);
    return output;
}
```

After that just add the paragraph to the document.

```
document.Add(CenteredParagraph("All the text to add that is centered.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Div div2 = new Div();
    div2.setPaddingLeft(35);
    div2.setPaddingRight(35);
    div2.setPaddingBottom(5);
    div2.add(new Paragraph().add(new Paragraph("Hola Mundo")
                    .setFontSize(12)
                    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED)
                    .setPaddingLeft(10)
            )
            .setPaddingBottom(4));
    document.add(div2);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).